# Ensemble average and law of large numbers

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ergodicity

In order to calculate the average of a macroscopic quantity such as energy, we need to average over all microstates of the system:

$$\langle E \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i E_i$$

where $n$ is the number of microstates. Each microstate has a probability associated with it, that is we have a probability distribution over microstates.

Law of large numbers states that as an experiment is repeated over and over, the empirical probability of the outcome approaches the theoretical (actual) probability of the outcome. In other words as we repeat the experiment over and over, the obtained distribution approaches the actual distribution.

Given that microstates change very rapidly, if we record all the microstates that appear in a sufficient long time interval (say $10$ seconds), should the distribution look like the actual one?

Comment: We cannot directly measure internal energy of thermodynamic systems. We can measure mass, and adopt Einsteinian $U=mc^2$ as measurement of internal energy, but even the most accurate measurements of mass of macroscopic systems we can do are too inaccurate and too slow to detect thermal fluctuations of internal energy.

Comment: This is one of the puzzles of statistical mechanics.  It is fairly clear (although not necessarily easy to prove rigorously) that if we allow a system to evolve over an arbitrarily long time, then we know what to expect from its time-averaged behavior.  Unfortunately, if you try to estimate the times required, they turn out to be stupendously large.  Yet in practice it turns out that you really only need to wait a much shorter time to reach a system that is practically indistinguishable from equilibrium.

Comment: @Buzz What makes the time needed a lot a shorter to reach a system that is practically indistinguishable from equilibrium? Is it because the most probable macrostate has a a lot (an overwhelming number) more microstates than the other macrostates?

Comment: @AntoniosSarikas That is certainly part of the answer, at least schematically.  However, getting a useful estimate of how long it takes to approach equilibrium turns out to be extremely difficult.